# trying to find the word down and dome (LIKE)

Tags: mysql, sql

quite new to SQL I appreciate the help!

```
select objects
from objectlist
where objects LIKE 'do%'
```

I am specially looking for dome and down and im stuck on wildcard expressions and my lack of understanding.

thanks again!

Comment: `RLIKE '^do.n$'` will match four letter words spelled *d  o  anything n* using regex. `LIKE 'do_n' does it with SQL's single character wildcard `_`.  Regexes take some effort to read and troubleshoot, but they're worth it.

Comment: Thanks O.Jones
if i had other values with do<a-z>e
could you provide an example using RLIKE where only dome and down will be returned?

I will read into regex, I appreciate the help so much!

Comment: Never mind! used '^attribute|attribute$'
this worked thanks :)

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for `'dome'` and `'down'`, then use `in`:

```
where objects in ('dome', 'down')
```

Comment: would you consider this using regular expression, very new to the concept :o

Comment: also!
Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen Gordon make a mistake before. Seriously. `in`. not `like`.

Comment: apologies, was very tired last night.

Answer (score 0):

Additional ANSWERS

@@@ ANSWER(2) @@@ RLIKE instead of LIKE

```
select objects
from objectlist
where objectives RLIKE '^do.n$'
```

@@@ANSWER(3)@@@ RLIKE instead of LIKE

```
select objects
from objectlist
where objectives RLIKE '^dome|down$'
```

@@@ ANSWER(4) @@@ REGEXP instead of LIKE
@ Best solution in this scenario. @

```
select objects
from objectlist
where objectives REGEXP '^dome|down$'
```

thanks again everybody!

Comment: Please do not copy existing answers into your answer post (or be very clear that you are using the other answers core solution and just fleshing it out a bit). Making an additional answer with your own ideas is appreciated though.